# File i/o in postscript

Tags: file, postscript

I wish data to read from or write into an external file by some file-operators in PostScript.

I created a file input.txt within the same folder (WINDOWS 7) as the PostScript-program. When Ghostscript interprets the line
(input.txt)(r) file
the error-message "-illegalfileaccess- in file" is produced.
What is wrong in my program-line?

I read concerning questions in this forum, but the answers didn't help me. What can I do now?

enricoernesto

Answer (score 5):

By convention, a postscript "document" should not access files. And to enforce this convention, GSView and Adobe Acrobat usually process documents with the `file` operator disabled so it cannot access files. With GSView, you should be able to edit the command-line (in the options, somewhere) to remove the `-DSAFER` string. With ghostscript (and its other incarnations like `ps2ps` and `ps2pdf`) you can also add `-DNOSAFER` to your command-line, and it should override any `-DSAFER` options earlier in the command string.

Comment: I put the -dNOSAFER - string via GSView/Options into the start-command of Ghostscript and now my ps-Program works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Try running this code. It will create a new file, output1.txt, then read that file, then write the the file back to output2.txt. If everyting is correct, you should have 2 files, otherwise you do not have write access to where the file is trying to be w

```
/outfile1 (output1.txt) (w) file def
outfile1 (blah blah blah) writestring
outfile1 closefile 


/inputfile (output1.txt) (r) file def
inputfile 100 string readstring
pop
inputfile closefile

/outfile2 (output2.txt) (w) file def
outfile2 exch writestring
outfile2 closefile
```

If that fails, try this one. if this works, it shows that the default location is not writable, but the explicit path allows writing, otherwise it is ghostscript which is not allowing writing.

```
/outfile1 (c:\\output1.txt) (w) file def
outfile1 (blah blah blah) writestring
outfile1 closefile 


/inputfile (c:\\output1.txt) (r) file def
inputfile 100 string readstring
pop
inputfile closefile

/outfile2 (c:\\output2.txt) (w) file def
outfile2 exch writestring
outfile2 closefile
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your program, there's no way anyone can help you without that.

Have you looked at the Ghostscript documentation on 'How Ghostscript finds files' ? If not you should do so.

You also need to post what command line you are using, for example if you are using -dSAFER then reading files outside of certain key locations is forbidden.