# how to extract location state from postscript?

Tags: rendering, postscript

I am writing a quiz generator, started using HTML which turns out to be hard to deterministically decide where things will be. So I am going to use postscript.
When I write out a question, and the box where the student is to write the answer, I need to know exactly where the box will be. This depends on the question text.

Inside the engine, I can easily access the x y cursor location that I am using to render.
The question is how to get that information outside the engine. I could write a file, though I read that is not considered good practice: [File i/o in postscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702146/file-i-o-in-postscript)

I could write c++ code that uses freetype to open the fonts, calculate the location, but that's doing the same work twice, in two different languages, and what if I want to render images in there? I want the rendering and calculation to be done in only one place.

Is there any way to do this cleanly, is there an alternate tool anyone can suggest? At the moment my only concept is to write the locations of each box out to a file during the render, which means running unsafe.

Comment: You can get the current point by using the currentpoint operator, which will return the x and y co-ordinates. Note that these are in the current user co-ordinate space so you may need to transform them using the Current Transformation Matrix depending on what further operations you plan on. It isn't clear what you intend to do with this information.. Writing a location to a file using some other rendering engine's notion of the current location is probably inaccurate, so I'd avoid that quite apart from the security implications of allowing a PostScript program to access random files.

Comment: @KenS Getting the current point is the easy part. I need to export a list of points as I render the page. The only way I can think to do this is to write the locations to a file.
Postscript default coordinates are in points. to reverse engineer from the resulting image I would have to scale to the DPI that the pdf was output, which is doable.

Comment: You can write the numbers to stdout (or stderr) to avoid writing a file (or at least avoid writing it using PostScript file operators), but if you want your PostScript program to communicate with an outside environment, then there's no avoiding I/O of some kind.

Comment: To avoid the possibility of unsafe programs, you could use the --permit-file-write control, which would allow Ghostscript (and this **is** Ghostscript-specific) to write **only** to the named file.